# ASP.NET: Custom dynamically populated site map (SiteMapProvider)

Tags: asp.net, sitemapprovider

I'm trying to write my first very own `SiteMapProvider` subclass. It is meant to be populated dynamically using a bunch of different database lookups, much like all of the examples I've found on the web.

However, there are a whole bunch of things that are quite unclear to me. Here are my two first questions:

- Why is `StaticSiteMapProvider` used in virtually everyone's project instead of `SiteMapProvider`? Since the class contains the name "static", I'm getting the impression that it's not as...well, dynamic as I want it.
- Can someone provide me with a super-minimalistic `SiteMapProvider` subclass which populates the map using only static data, i.e. no database access, etc.?

Comment: do you have links to the resources and examples that you have read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SiteMapProvider` can be tottaly dynamic. For example it can make dynamic lookup just for nodes. In contrast with `StaticSiteMapProvider` you should know whole structure. So this for you to decide what to choose.

You can look at the `XmlSiteMapProvider`, this is good example of "static" map provider.

```
public class CoolMapProvider : StaticSiteMapProvider
{
    public override SiteMapNode BuildSiteMap()
    {
        var root = new SiteMapNode(this, "test", "~/test.aspx");
        base.AddNode(root, null);

        base.AddNode(new SiteMapNode(this, "test-child", "~/test_child.aspx"), root);

        return root;
    }
}
```

I did not checked this, but should work.

Comment: This all looks very nice, but could you give me an example of how I would add subnodes to "test"?

Comment: FWIW, I had to override `GetRootDoneCore` as well for it to work.

Comment: Answer updated, you have to use `base.AddNode`. Refarding `GetRootDoneCore`, I did this ages before, so cannot remember everything, sorry..

Comment: Funny, there is full example on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.staticsitemapprovider.aspx , take a look.