# Navigate to Sitemap from StaticSiteMapProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap, sitemapprovider

I'm trying to build an ASP site map dynamically to provide to Google Webmaster Tools. I believe I have it finished and am trying to test it...but I can't for the life of me figure out how to navigate to my sitemap. xD

I've built a class that extends `StaticSiteMapProvider` and referenced it in my web config.

```
[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]    
public class SiteMapConfig : StaticSiteMapProvider
{
    SiteMapNode _root;

    ArticleRepository _articles = new ArticleRepository();
    OpportunityRepository _opportunities = new OpportunityRepository();

    public override SiteMapNode BuildSiteMap()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            var root = GetRootNodeCore();

            var newsNode = new SiteMapNode(this, "News", "~/News/", "News");
            this.AddNode(newsNode, root);

            foreach (var article in _articles.GetAll())
            {
                var encodedTitle = URLEncoding.MakeUserFriendlyURLValue(article.Title);
                var articleNode = new SiteMapNode(this, "Article:" + article.ID, "~/News/" + article.ID + "/" + encodedTitle + "/", article.Title);
                this.AddNode(articleNode, newsNode);
            }

            var gamesNode = new SiteMapNode(this, "Games", "~/Games/", "Games");
            this.AddNode(gamesNode, root);

            var aboutNode = new SiteMapNode(this, "About", "~/About/", "About");
            this.AddNode(aboutNode, root);

            var OpportunitiesNode = new SiteMapNode(this, "Opportunities", "~/Opportunities/", "Opportunities");
            this.AddNode(OpportunitiesNode, root);

            foreach (var opportunity in _opportunities.GetAll())
            {
                var encodedTitle = URLEncoding.MakeUserFriendlyURLValue(opportunity.Title);
                var opportunityNode = new SiteMapNode(this, "Opportunity:" + opportunity.ID, "~/Opportunity/" + opportunity.ID + "/" + encodedTitle + "/", opportunity.Title);
                this.AddNode(opportunityNode, OpportunitiesNode);
            }

        }

        return _root;
    }

    protected override SiteMapNode GetRootNodeCore()
    {
        if (_root == null)
        {
            _root = new SiteMapNode(this, "Home", "~/", "[REDACTED]");
            this.AddNode(_root);
        }

        return _root;
    }
}
```

`Web.Config`:

```
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

<!-- TW: Added to configure site map -->
<siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="SiteMapConfig">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SiteMapConfig" type="Daemon.Sites.Company.SiteMapConfig, Daemon.Sites.Company" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

How can I see this in xml form?

Is there another step that isn't mentioned in all of my examples?
([Example 1](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/database-driven-site-maps/building-a-custom-database-driven-site-map-provider-cs), [Example 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16860/Building-a-dynamic-SiteMap-in-ASP-NET-for-a-la), [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716573/asp-net-custom-dynamically-populated-site-map-sitemapprovider/1716613#1716613))

I've tried: `"~/Sitemap", "~/Web.sitemap", "~/sitemap.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test my site map provider by referencing it from a site map datasource and binding it to a treeview. However, this wasn't an acceptable format for Google.

Ultimately I decided to scrap the above code and go with a different approach for creating a dynamic sitemap xml:

`SiteMap.aspx`

```
<%@ Page ContentType="text/xml" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteMap.aspx.cs" Inherits="Daemon.Sites.Company.SiteMap" %>

<!-- Cache this page for 1 day -->
<%@ OutputCache Duration="86400" VaryByParam="none" %>

<asp:repeater id="RepeaterSiteMap" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <url>
            <loc><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Location") %></loc>
            <priority><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Priority") %></priority>
        </url>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </urlset> 
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

`SiteMap.aspx.cs`

```
public partial class SiteMap : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<SiteMapEntry> entries = new List<SiteMapEntry>();

        entries.Add(new SiteMapEntry()
        {
            Location = "http://www.[redacted].com/",
            Priority = 1.0
        });

        entries.Add(new SiteMapEntry()
        {
            Location = "http://www.[redacted].com/About/",
            Priority = 0.9
        });

        entries.Add(new SiteMapEntry()
        {
            Location = "http://www.[redacted].com/Games/",
            Priority = 0.8
        });

        entries.Add(new SiteMapEntry()
        {
            Location = "http://www.[redacted].com/Opportunities/",
            Priority = 0.7
        });

        using (var opportunities = new OpportunityRepository())
        {
            foreach (var opportunity in opportunities.GetAll())
            {
                var encodedTitle = URLEncoding.MakeUserFriendlyURLValue(opportunity.Title);
                entries.Add(new SiteMapEntry()
                {
                    Location = "http://www.[redacted].com/Opportunity/" + opportunity.ID + "/" + encodedTitle + "/",
                    Priority = 0.6
                });
            }
        }

        entries.Add(new SiteMapEntry()
        {
            Location = "http://www.[redacted].com/News/",
            Priority = 0.5
        });

        using (var articles = new ArticleRepository())
        {
            foreach (var article in articles.GetAll())
            {
                var encodedTitle = URLEncoding.MakeUserFriendlyURLValue(article.Title);
                entries.Add(new SiteMapEntry()
                {
                    Location = "http://www.[redacted].com/News/" + article.ID + "/" + encodedTitle + "/",
                    Priority = 0.4
                });
            }
        }

        this.RepeaterSiteMap.DataSource = entries;
        this.RepeaterSiteMap.DataBind();
    }
}

public class SiteMapEntry
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public double Priority { get; set; }
}
```